# Rating is not correctly displaying in HTC

Tags: android, widget, rating

I am having rating widget with style, It is displayed good in some devices but having the problem with some devices like with HTC
My xml is :

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout3" 
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <RatingBar android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:numStars="5" android:stepSize="0.1"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleIndicator" 
            android:id="@+id/ratingbar_incident"                
            android:isIndicator="false"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/textViewVote" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dip" 
            android:textColor="@color/black" 
            android:text="(0 votes)" android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

.[image]

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should look out for `style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleIndicator"`

`The smaller RatingBar style ( ratingBarStyleSmall) and the larger indicator-only style (`**`ratingBarStyleIndicator`**`) do not support user interaction and should only be used as indicators.`

Also :

`When using a RatingBar that supports user interaction, placing widgets to the`**`left or right of the RatingBar is discouraged.`**``

Reference: [RatingBar - documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html)

Comment: what android do you have on your HTC? 

You can try this workaround, I haven't had time to test it yet: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2324#c9